# BadHttpRequestException: Unexpected end of request content

Tags: asp.net-core

An unhandled exception was thrown by the application:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Unexpected end of request content.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException.Throw(RequestRejectionReason reason)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1ContentLengthMessageBody.ReadAsyncInternal(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FormPipeReader.ReadFormAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.InnerReadFormAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.ReadForm()
   at IQF.Framework.Middleware.ExceptionHandleMiddleware.HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception ex) in /src/IQF.Framework/Middleware/ExceptionHandleMiddleware.cs:line 51
   at IQF.Framework.Middleware.ExceptionHandleMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in /src/IQF.Framework/Middleware/ExceptionHandleMiddleware.cs:line 40
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing source code enables members to offer more specific advice. Thanks!

Comment: All we know is, that you get this exception when you do something (what?) in some (which?) situations / always? for all routes / some routes? using a request(?) we don't know. There's nothing that would help anyone to help you. Also, what have you tried so far? - Please invest some more time to post your issue if you want others to invest time in helping you.